# Ubuntu is very slow in my Laptop Asus N51VN

Tags: nvidia, graphics, laptop, asus, process

My laptop has a 4G ram and 500G hard with the Intel core 2 duo but Ubuntu is very very slow in my laptop I try `Ubuntu studio` `Ubuntu 14.04` `Ubuntu 14.10` `Ubuntu 15.04` instead Windows operation work perfectly fine even `window 8.1`.
When i use Firefox and search in net the OP going slower than before and CPU process still in 100%...
[image]

I find [this page](http://www.linlap.com/asus_n51vn) and in that says for processor :

> Processor Works   Some kernel versions need thermal.psv=-1

But is can't fix the problem and can't find `thermal.psv=-1`

My laptop is Asus N51VN

------------------------------------ update in (6 , April , 2015)

I try Xubuntu and Fedora but the problem still there... in Xubuntu and XFCE speed a little bit better but in heavy use operation cams to process slow,
in Fedora I find the graphic card is not installed...
my Graphic card is :

> Nvidia Gforce 240M

how can find and install properly graphic card in both of ubuntu and fedora?

Comment: Try Xubuntu and see if it's just your video compositing for Unity hitting processor instead of the GPU.

Comment: I'm using xfce and nothing change, I like to use unity ...

Comment: Please check your CPU usage with the terminal command `top` instead of system-monitor. It takes many resources just for displaying that CPU graph, at least on my system with Intel Centrino Duo 2x2.0GHz...

Comment: I try 'top' almost firefox and compiz take the hole of process

Comment: Compiz is specific to Ubuntu's desktop environment Unity. You will not have that when you use xfce for example (I think).

Comment: I live compiz and set many animation with `compizConfig`, but the most of process it used by `firefox`, whatever i try xfce and nothing change

Comment: can you present Desktop it's have the top bar exactly like unity with top menu?

Answer (score 1):

Many installations get paralysed by "tracker", a useless tool blocking 95% of ressources for quite a while. In a terminal invoke "top" to find if thats the reason. Kill the tracker processes and check back. Find more about this bloating tool on your search engine. As mentioned before: Do avoid Gnome! Use XFCE4 or LXDE. I use even much older Laptops with it having great performance experience.

Answer (score 0):

find graphic card drivers because it looks like your cpu is doing all the work.
I'm using ASUS N55S and my CPU is usually 5% or 10%. The Ram was a bit unnerving as it registered at 100% but that is how Linux works it keeps 100% ready for you.

Comment: For install graphic driver I have to go to `Software & update` and go to `Additional Driver` tab and select one of Driver that's offer to me?